# UITextView and UIMenuController arrow direction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a UITextView with a toolbar above it, when the text is selected the Black menu (cut, copy, paste, etc) covers this up, I'd like the menu to always have the arrow up, I have tried:

```
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setArrowDirection:UIMenuControllerArrowUp];
```

but it doesn't work the arrow is still down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setTargetRect:CGRectMake(0,100,320,200) inView:self.view];` and see the down-arrow

Comment: But it is a text view so the target rect depends on where the word is, you can't make it appear manually.